# Why is there no MonadMask instance for ExceptT?

Tags: haskell, exception, monad-transformers

Edward Kmett's *exceptions* library does not provide a [MonadMask](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.18/exceptions-0.8.3/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadMask) instance for [ExceptT](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.18/transformers-0.5.2.0/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT).

[Ben Gamari once asked about this](https://github.com/ekmett/exceptions/issues/35) and then concluded that it was explained by the documentation. This is the closest relevant-looking passage I can find:

> Note that this package does provide a `MonadMask` instance for `CatchT`. This instance is *only* valid if the base monad provides no ability to provide multiple exit. For example, `IO` or `Either` would be invalid base monads, but `Reader` or `State` would be acceptable.

But its meaning is not self-evident to me. What does "multiple exit" mean and why does it prohibit a `MonadMask` instance?

[Michael Snoyman also writes](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2014/06/exceptions-transformers):

> [...] 'MonadMask', which allows you to guarantee that certain actions are run, even in the presence of exceptions (both synchronous and asynchronous). In order to provide that guarantee, the monad stack must be able to control its flow of execution. In particular, this excludes instances for [...] Monads with multiple exit points, such as `ErrorT` over `IO`.

Perhaps it would be more clear to ask this alternative question: If we set aside transformers and consider the slightly simpler type:

```
data IOEither a = IOEither { unIOEither :: IO (Either String a) }
    deriving Functor
```

It *seems* that we can in fact write a `MonadMask` instance:

```
instance Applicative IOEither where
    pure = IOEither . return . Right
    IOEither fIO <*> IOEither xIO = IOEither $
        fIO >>= either (return . Left) (\f -> (fmap . fmap) f xIO)

instance Monad IOEither where
    IOEither xIO >>= f = IOEither $
        xIO >>= either (return . Left) (\x -> unIOEither (f x))

instance MonadThrow IOEither where
    throwM e = IOEither (throwM @IO e)

instance MonadCatch IOEither where
    catch (IOEither aIO) f = IOEither $ catch @IO aIO (unIOEither . f)

instance MonadMask IOEither where
    mask f = IOEither $ mask @IO $ \restore ->
        unIOEither $ f (IOEither . restore . unIOEither)
    uninterruptibleMask f = IOEither $ uninterruptibleMask @IO $ \restore ->
        unIOEither $ f (IOEither . restore . unIOEither)
```

Does this instance I've written not work properly?

Comment: Readers interested in this question should also consider Snoyman's [*Exceptions Best Practices in Haskell*](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/11/exceptions-best-practices-haskell) for an opinion on why `IO (Either String a)` is simply not a type one should be using.

Comment: Note that an instance is available since exceptions-0.9.0.

Comment: New question: [Why is there a MonadMask instance for ExceptT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318471)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is a program that demonstrates the problem with your instances: You can exit early with `Left` and thereby cause the finalizer to never be run. This is in contrast to the law stated in the docs for `MonadMask` which require that for `` f `finally` g `` `g` is executed regardless of what happens in `f`. The reason why the finalizer is never run is quite simple: If no exception is thrown `finally` (or `bracket` which is how `finally` is implemented) just uses `>>=` to run the finalizer afterwards but `>>=` does not execute the right argument if the left returns `Left`.

```
data IOEither a = IOEither { unIOEither :: IO (Either String a) }
    deriving Functor

instance Applicative IOEither where
    pure = IOEither . return . Right
    IOEither fIO <*> IOEither xIO = IOEither $
        fIO >>= either (return . Left) (\f -> (fmap . fmap) f xIO)

instance Monad IOEither where
    IOEither xIO >>= f = IOEither $
        xIO >>= either (return . Left) (\x -> unIOEither (f x))

instance MonadThrow IOEither where
    throwM e = IOEither (throwM @IO e)

instance MonadCatch IOEither where
    catch (IOEither aIO) f = IOEither $ catch @IO aIO (unIOEither . f)

instance MonadMask IOEither where
    mask f = IOEither $ mask @IO $ \restore ->
        unIOEither $ f (IOEither . restore . unIOEither)
    uninterruptibleMask f = IOEither $ uninterruptibleMask @IO $ \restore ->
        unIOEither $ f (IOEither . restore . unIOEither)

instance MonadIO IOEither where
  liftIO x = IOEither (Right <$> x)

main :: IO ()
main = void $ unIOEither $ finally (IOEither (return (Left "exit")))
                                   (liftIO (putStrLn "finalizer"))
```

Comment: Exactly right. This is why we skipped the instance. We wracked our brains over ways to fix it and it'd have been nice to have but it doesn't pass the obvious finalizer law. In the end we decided against having an illegal (if "obvious") instance or figuring out phrasing that would allow us to weaken the laws in ways prone to user error.

Comment: @Edward KMETT It seems that we could write a specialized bracket-like operation like `bracketE :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> ExceptT e IO c) -> ExceptT e IO c`, couldn't we? One that didn't depend on `MonadMask`s functions and used `IO`'s `bracket` directly.

Comment: @danidiaz: See the HEAD branch. https://github.com/ekmett/exceptions/commit/e8cd863ebaf1357091dc7df331bf5c9e73ac21a7 from a little while back added something vaguely in this vein. We're currently shaking that out to see if we like it.

Answer (score 2):

> A class for **monads which provide for the ability to account for all possible exit points from a computation**, and to mask asynchronous exceptions. Continuation-based monads, and stacks such as `ErrorT e IO` which provide for multiple failure modes, are invalid instances of this class.

When you use `ErrorT`/`ExceptT` with `IO`, having "multiple exit points" refers to the fact that you can have either a runtime exception or an exception thrown in the Monad. Either of which would end the computation.

```
runExceptT $ do
  error "This is an exit point."
  throwError "This is another exit point."
  return 23
```

It would be possible to write a `MonadMask` for `ExceptT` that would be valid for all `ExceptT e m a` with the precondition that the underlying monad `m` is *not* IO. Hence the huge warning about using `CatchT` with `IO` (Doing so invalidates the `MonadMask` instance).

Comment: Isn't my `IOEither` isomorphic to `ExceptT String IO` - meaning the "underlying monad" *is* `IO`? You can end the computation in the `IOEither` monad with `throwIO` or with `return . Left`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's no longer true since [**exceptions** *v0.9.0*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.9.0/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadMask) which has been uploaded to the **hackage** 25 Feb 2018.

P.S. *0.9.0* is considered deprecated, *0.10.0* is recommended to use (see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.0/changelog).