# Why is there a MonadMask instance for ExceptT?

Tags: haskell, exception, monad-transformers

In a previous question, I asked

[Why is there no MonadMask instance for ExceptT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966893/)

and got a number of compelling answers, including from the library author, why there cannot exist a lawful instance.

As of February 2018, the [exceptions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions) library *does* now have an instance of [MonadMask](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.0/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadMask) for [ExceptT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:ExceptT).

So now I'm asking the exact opposite question: Why are the answers to my previous question incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the [`exceptions`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.0/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#v:generalBracket) library has the answer in its docs:

> This method was added in version 0.9.0 of this library. Previously, implementation of functions like `bracket` and `finally` in this module were based on the `mask` and `uninterruptibleMask` functions only, disallowing some classes of transformers from having `MonadMask` instances (notably multi-exit-point transformers like `ExceptT`). If you are a library author, you'll now need to provide an implementation for this method...

(Note: the type of `generalBracket` were changed in 0.10, don't use 0.9).

Comment: The doc isn't quite clear as to why the addition of `generalBracket` permits new law-abiding instances. Through the commit history I've tracked down a [blog post](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/02/monadmask-vs-monadbracket) which gives the motivation for the change.